# How to use a 3.5mm headset on a normal phone?

Tags: port, adapter, phone

I'd like to use a 3.5mm headset instead of the normal phone receiver (with a rj9 plug), I can find only 2.5mm (male) to rj9 male adapter, but it is not what I need. Any hint?

Comment: Why not just build it yourself? get a spare RJ9, a 3.5mm socket and frankencable it by chopping off one end, and soldering it to a pair of 3.5 mm sockets

Answer (score 0):

There are several places that sell 2.5mm to 3.5mm connectors. Make certain that it's got the two rings on the jack, not just the one, otherwise you'll end up with mono output.

I got one of these a while back and hooked it up to my Nokia 6275i without problem:

http://www.dealextreme.com/details.dx/sku.733

Comment: I need the opposite adaptor. I need the *female* to be 3.5mm (or 2.5mm I can find one more adaptor easily). RJ9 is mono so it's not that the problem, the thing is I need need 2x3.5mm because I need microphone too.

Comment: It's not clear from the link, but that's a 2.5mm male to 3.5mm female. I used it to plug male 3.5mm headphones into my Nokia's 2.5mm female jack.

It supports stereo, but I don't know if it supports microphone or not, sorry.